# Bash: Running a background service for the duration of another process

Tags: linux, bash, ssh-tunnel

I am running some automated scripts. For some tasks I sometimes need a ephemral background "service" to run. For example, I want to setup an ssh tunnel, run a test, and then have the tunnel removed.

ATM I am using some lengthy code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
function automated_task(){
    socksProxyTimeout=120
    ssh -A -D 9999 some_server "sleep $socksProxyTimeout; " &
    sockProxyPid=$!
    sleep 3

    function cleanUp(){
        echo shutting down background processes...
        kill -9 $sockProxyPid || true
        cd ../../
    }

    trap 'cleanUp' EXIT
    run_selenium_with_proxy
}
automated_task
```

I do not like this solution much, because I think cleanup is only called once the entire script exits, not just "automated_task". I would really like to have the code as local as possible. What I'd really like to do is somehow specify for a background process to run only as long as the foreground process is still running.

Answer (score 0):

I would try storing the child process ID as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645713/bash-start-and-kill-child-process)

```
sshPID=""

disconnect() 
   if [ "x$sshPID" != "x" ]; then
       kill "$sshPID"
       sshPID=""
   fi
}

connect() {
    ssh -A -D 9999 some_server "sleep $socksProxyTimeout; " & sshPID=$!
    trap 'disconnect' EXIT
}

connect
sleep 3
disconnect
```

You may be able to use `ssh -O exit some_server` instead of kill, depending on if you use `ControlMaster` setup.  (see ssh docs).

Comment: That's not a good solution. without using TRAP, ssh will remain open if the script recieves a break.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to use this as well as the TRAP.  Editing answer